# How to invert SVG textpath so the text won't be upside down?

Tags: javascript, svg

I can't figure out how to draw the svg path using javascript so the text won't be upside down. I suppose it should be drown in the opposite direction, but I am a bit struggling with it, so would really appreciate your help.

Trying to get this

[image]

But getting this instead

[image]

Here is the link to the codepen https://codepen.io/Arneric/pen/yLboapr and the function I use to generate the path:

```
const setPath = (cx, cy, r, deg) => {
  let theta = deg*Math.PI/180,
      dx = -r*Math.cos(theta),
      dy = r*Math.sin(theta)

  return `M ${cx} ${cy}
          m ${dx} ${dy}
          a ${r},${r} 0 1,0 ${-2*dx}, ${-2*dy}
          a ${r}, ${r} 0 1,0 ${2*dx},${2*dy}`
}
```

Would be perfect if someone could update this function, so we would get the desired result. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes I've made:

1. I've changed the sweep-flag of the arcs from 0 to 1
2. for the setPath I'm using deg = 90 instead of 0 and I'm deleting the `transform: rotate(90deg)`. Alternatively you can use the transformation with deg = 180

Also I've changed the radius r to something smallet otherWise the text will be drawn outside the svg canvas. You can opt for a different viewBox

```js
const setPath = (cx, cy, r, deg) => {
  let theta = deg*Math.PI/180,
      dx = -r*Math.cos(theta),
      dy = r*Math.sin(theta)

  return `M ${cx+dx} ${cy+dy}
          
          a ${r},${r} 0 1,1 ${-2*dx}, ${-2*dy}
          a ${r}, ${r} 0 1,1 ${2*dx},${2*dy}`
}

let path = document.getElementById("circle-path");
path.setAttribute("d", setPath(100,100,70,90))
```

```css
svg{
  font-size:10px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200">

    <path stroke='red'
          fill="none"
          id='circle-path'
          d=''></path>
    
  <text 
  ref='big'
  class='text big-text text-uppercase'>
    <textPath text-anchor="middle"
              startOffset="50%"
              xlink:href="#circle-path">SOME TEXT THAT GOES ALONG THE CIRCLE PATH
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
  dx = -r*Math.cos(theta),
  dy = r*Math.sin(theta)
```

You could use this:

```
  dx = r*Math.cos(theta),
  dy = -r*Math.sin(theta)
```

Comment: Not really... still getting it upside down, just rotated... Try to upload the pen and you will see :/